# `$ is not defined` for jQuery

Tags: jquery, undefined

I am using the following code for a php page, while I am receiving this error.
Can someone suggest anything?
I am able to view the source for JS files, when I visit them via links in the `view-source:` in Chrome..
This is a very small page, while the entire content for this page is as below:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Code Library: Localhost Repository</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="js/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(function(){
    $(function(){ $("select, input:checkbox, input:radio, input:file").uniform(); });
   });
  </script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uniform.default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
 </head>

 <body>
  <form method="post" action="/index.php" class="jqtransform">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><label for="title">Code::Title</label></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="title" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table>   
   <input type="hidden" name="CodeSubmitted" value="Y"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Add Code Snippet"/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you nest two document ready calls (`$(function() { $(function() {}); });`)?

Comment: No need to change the title. To confirm that the issue has been resolved, once you're able, click the large checkmark next to the answer that was most helpful.

Comment: yep.. but that needs a 15 minute time. :)

Comment: I removed the "resolved" thing - accept the best answer after the time limit has passed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're using `href` instead of `src` in the `script` tags.

Comment: Oh man.. thank you.. and I was just seeing the code again and again and won't know why. Yep, sometimes, I just get too messy and forget the simplest things. :)

Answer (score 2):

On the lines 4 and 5 it should be a src-Attribute not a href-Attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script tags you need to use `src` not `href`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this code is wrong thats why jquery is not loaded and giving error

it should be src instead of href , might be a typo error

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
```

one more thing , why did you add function inside a function

```
$(function(){
                $(function(){ $("select, input:checkbox, input:radio, input:file").uniform(); });
            }
```

);